# how to sort Date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
scheduled_datetime

2016-12-07 10:30:00
2016-12-07 13:30:00
2016-11-06  22:30:00
2016-12-06  23:30:00
2016-19-08  22:30:00
```

sorting first date wise if date is same then sort by time

```
select * 
from mytable 
where scheduled_datetime > now()  
order by scheduled_datetime;
```

from this query i have to find date which greater than today time  please suggest me where am doing wrong .

Comment: Question is or sorting or filtering. Actually both are happening in your current query.

Comment: Do you want to sort _ascending_ or _descending_?

Comment: assenting and descending in both order base one feature and past date and time

Comment: @MakleeLee I don't quite understand your comment at all. By the way, if you sort `DateTime` values in _MySql_ there is no need to sort date and time seperately. It's just doing this automatically.

Comment: @MakleeLee Please show your expected output if possible.

Comment: @MakleeLee Could you provide any feedback to our solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only output dates which are greater than today, then you need to use `DATE()` to only compare to the date values of `scheduled_datetime`:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where DATE(scheduled_datetime) > NOW()  
order by scheduled_datetime asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have following 3 options :

```
--If you want to fetch records greater than current date & time
select * from mytable where scheduled_datetime > NOW()
--If you want to fetch records greater than current date
select * from mytable where scheduled_datetime > CURDATE()
--If you want to fetch records greater than current time
select * from mytable where scheduled_datetime > CURTIME()
```

You can use ORDER BY ASC or DESC according, in what order you want to get data.